# How to export over 100,000 records from ms dynamics to excel

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Currently I am only able to export 100,000 rows of data when exporting from ms dynamics to excel. How can I export up to 1,000,000 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this XrmToolBox plugin:
Export to Excel https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Ryr.XrmToolBox.ExportToExcel/

keep in mind that you have also the limitation of Excel format: 1,048,576 rows